# How to use the Cinnamon panel when using Awesome Window Manager in Cinnamon?

Tags: cinnamon, awesome, gnome-panel

I am using `cinnamon 2.2.16-1`, `awesome 3.5.5-1` and [awesome-cinnamon](https://aur.archlinux.org/packages/awesome-cinnamon/) from the Arch Linux [AUR](https://aur.archlinux.org/).  The `awesome-cinnamon` package basically just creates the `.desktop` and `.session` files to load `cinnamon` with `awesome wm` as the window manager.  This is almost perfect for me, but I would like to experiment with using the `cinnamon` panel in addition to or instead of the `awesome` `wibox`, because the `cinnamon` panel has attractive icons for the audio, wifi and power controls.

I can't seem to find any way to start the `cinnamon` panel.  I am left thinking that the `cinnamon` panel must be part of `cinnamon's` window manager.  It seems from googling that there used to be a program `gnome-panel` and `cinnamon-panel`, but these don't seem to exist anymore.  Does anyone know of a way to get this working?

cat /usr/share/xsessions/awesome-cinnamon.desktop:

```
[Desktop Entry]
Name=Awesome Cinnamon
Comment=Dynamic window manager
TryExec=/usr/bin/cinnamon
Exec=cinnamon-session-cinnamon --session=awesome
Type=XSession
```

cat /usr/share/cinnamon-session/sessions/awesome.session:

```
[Cinnamon Session]
Name=Awesome session
RequiredComponents=cinnamon-settings-daemon;awesome;
RequiredProviders=windowmanager;notifications;
DefaultProvider-windowmanager=awesome
DefaultProvider-notifications=notification-daemon
```

$ cinnamon-<kbd>Tab</kbd><kbd>Tab</kbd>:

```
cinnamon-desktop-editor           cinnamon-screensaver-lock-dialog
cinnamon-extension-tool           cinnamon-session
cinnamon-json-makepot             cinnamon-session-cinnamon
cinnamon-launcher                 cinnamon-session-cinnamon2d
cinnamon-looking-glass            cinnamon-session-properties
cinnamon-menu-editor              cinnamon-session-quit
cinnamon-screensaver              cinnamon-settings
cinnamon-screensaver-command      cinnamon-settings-users
```

Comment: The [`PKGBUILD`](https://aur.archlinux.org/packages/awesome-cinnamon/), is about 8 months old, the [latest upstream change](https://github.com/clfarron4/archlinux-awesome-cinnamon/) as well. I think you're better of asking on github or leave feedback at the AUR page.

Comment: It's really not clear to me if this is a bug or a normal consequence of using awesome as a window manager. Does the cinnamon panel not show up because the AUR package is behind or is that the normal behavior of switching WM's?

Comment: The pkgbuild lists cinnamon as a dependency. It could have changed in the meanwhile

Comment: @JKav77 have you been able to solve this issue?

Answer (score 0):

Short answer: I don't think that is possible.

As discussed [here](https://github.com/linuxmint/Cinnamon/issues/4895) the cinnamon panel is now a plugin for the muffin window manager, which is what cinnamon uses as its window manager (the program called cinnamon launched by cinnamon_launcher).  Therefore it is not possible to use the cinnamon panel with a different window manager.

I was able to run the mate-panel panel with a different window manager (I use fvwm) and the rest of the cinnamon environment.  But probably most of what people think of as cinnamon is tied to the cinnamon window manager (aka muffin).